# Sprite Kit: Splice node image in 2 different nodes (similar to fruit ninja)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I was wondering if there is any method which can help me break an image in 2 pieces (or multiple) using sprite kit. The behaviour I try to achieve is similar to fruit ninja. I have loaded a sprite on the screen, a basic image, but I don't know if I can "cut" it in 2 pieces using Sprite Kit.

Comment: what about trying to use two nodes and position them right beside each other and apply an impulse as they are cut?

Comment: i thought about this, but I want to follow the gesture when making the cut so it feels more natural

Comment: The split effect in fruit ninja didn't follow the gesture. Look carefully and you will find fruits always cut in half, no matter where your gesture covers. The way to make things look more natural is to add 2 or 3 ways of the cut animation.

Comment: then I would like to achieve a different kind of behaviour, any suggestions ?